# Как удалить версионирование файлов компьюетра в гите

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit, git-branch

Всем привет, такой вопрос.
Я только недавно начал работу с системой контроля версий git, как оказалось, все, что я делал на компьютере (в тч для работы с проектом) отслеживалось гитом и теперь у меня в мастер ветке более 10к изменений.
Я пробовал через vscode отказаться от всех изменений, но это не помогло, более 10к файлов остались на своем месте.
Могу ли я удалить папку .git с компьютера, чтобы исчезло отслеживание?

Comment: Можете, если в ней нет ничего ценного

Comment: А если есть? как отключить это версионирование?

Comment: А что конкретно ценного у вас там есть?

Comment: Там файлы проекта, над которыми работала команда. Я больше к тому, не удалится ли из гитлаба проект в таком случае? не испорчу ли я все)

Comment: Во-первых, удаление файлов на вашем компьютере абсолютно никак не повлияет на файлы других компьютеров, в том числе гитлаба. Во-вторых, вы уверены, что файлы проекта у вас лежат именно в папке .git, а не в папке проекта?

Comment: В конце концов, если вам слишком стрёмно удалять папку .git, вы всегда можете просто переместить её или запаковать в архив и посмотреть что изменится, и лишь затем, убедившись, что всё хорошо, удалить

Comment: Наверное, вы правы, посмотрел в папке git - не вижу ничего кроме коммитов, веток, логов и тд. 
То есть, удаляя со своего компьютера папку git у меня отключится версионирование, но при этом в гитлабе ничего не изменится?

Comment: Вы потом всегда сможете повторно сделать `git clone` для повторного скачивания папки .git с гитлаба. Если вы уверены, что «коммиты, ветки, логи и тд» вам не нужны и всё нужное есть на гитлабе, то папку .git можно удалять

Comment: Спасибо большое! попробую заархивировать.